# Work at a solid stressful job or change during tumultuous times?

Tags: stress

What factors should consider when deciding to stay at a job that I know I will not be fired from, even though it is stressful or leave to pursue other opportunities even though the job market is very scarce?

Comment: I'm not really following what you are asking here.

Comment: How can you be sure that the other place's work would be less stressful?  If it is in the beginning stages, there are a lot of different things that could happen that would make it more stressful I'd argue as well as possibly not being able to pay as well as the company may be trying to keep its expenses low.

Comment: @DanteH your question is a bit difficult to know a definitive answer to. If you look at the [help page](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) you'll see questions like this generally are off topic - only YOU can know the exact answer to your "should I do XXX..."  if you [edit] your question to focus more on the aspects which affect your decision it will be much more on topic here. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Dante, please don't let the hostile behavior scare you away. One rule on The Workplace SE is to be nice, and rude behavior isn't something we tolerate here. With that said, I'm not sure you're question is an actual question as it stands, and I think this might not be something we can help with as it might not fit our Q&A model. However, please feel free to try and edit to focus more on a specific question you have. This will likely be here for awhile for you to come back and edit. Hope this helps!

Comment: This still appears off-topic because "Questions seeking advice on what job to take, what skills to learn, etc. are off-topic as the answers are rarely useful to anyone else."

Comment: Dante, this is a decision that nobody but you can make. I'm almost 60 and I've had to make that kind of decision (again) in the last few years. But no outsider can know what the value of "less stress" is to you, nor how hard it is for you personally.  You sound like you need to change something, but look at all the alternatives first, and be sure you consider the full effects of whatever path you take (even though you can't see very far down the path.)

Comment: This [answer of mine](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/15150/2322) to a different question might e helpful.